# lighted rain behind a window

Tags: materials, particles, light

i'm fighting with an effect I would like to achieve using particles & Blender (if possible Eevee, for rendering time concerns).

I want to make rain INSIDE a box, and to light that rain.

[image]

The lighting is very important.  You should really understand were the light source is, by watching the rain.
But the light itself doesn't really show up.
I did a lot of tests with particles, materials, volumetrics, etc; but can't get close to it:

[image]

I also had tests with particles emitting light, the problem being that I really need water drops to be illuminated realisticly - and to react to my light setup as I update it.

Does anyone know how to do this (and if it is doable) ?
Here's [my current blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjc6yrcvwx7nmce/testHouse012.blend?dl=1).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: perhaps you could use a glass material for the rain, with the IOR set for rain settings, and use a plane above them with an emission material.  There's a chance you've already tried this, but I'd thought I'd say it just in case

Comment: yes, already done the glass & the emission plane above it...

Answer (score 1):

For the inner illumination of your drops remember to not make the drops 100% transparent. Look at the difference for value =1 and value=0.95
[image]
[image]
I don't think that there's any other option than doing this and adding a LOT of samples.. :(

You would have to modify the particles to be dynamic thought the flight, so their shape changes very slightly, so each moment they reflect light in a slightly other direction. 
Also, cycles sucks at caustics. Your lightning setup would use refraction for the drops themselves to be lit "from inside", and reflective to get the shimmering effect on the video.